How to disable the print button for in docusign, for a signer or for the envelope?
I'm using the API to create an Envelope and to request a signature through my app.
When a signer displays the document, there is a button to print the document.
I'd like to request the API to disable the button for some signers or if not possible for all the signers of the Envelope.
I found this answer : How to disable and hide the print and separate and combined pdf download option for docusign signer, where it seems possible by modifying the resources of the account. I haven't try yet because it is not exactly what I want.
I expect something in the API to set this property for the envelope or for the recipient.

One other way you can do this is using a feature called Focused View.
This feature improved the embedding experience for developers such that you actually use a DIV element in your page and the UI that renders in there looks like a component and has fewer controls and menus etc.
You can find the code example in this article - https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-focused-view/
Here is the HTML and JavaScript needed to render:
<br />
<h2>The document has been embedded with focused view.</h2>
<br />

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset=\"utf-8\" />
    <title>Signing</title>
    <style>
        html,
        body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            font: 13px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        }

        .docusign-agreement {
            width: 75%;
            height: 800px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class=\"docusign-agreement\" id=\"agreement\"></div>
</body>
</html>

<p><a>Continue</a></p>

<script>
    window.DocuSign.loadDocuSign('" . $integrationKey . "')
        .then((docusign) => {
            const signing = docusign.signing({
                url: '" . $url . "',
                displayFormat: 'focused',
                style: {
                    /** High-level variables that mirror our existing branding APIs. Reusing the branding name here for familiarity. */
                    branding: {
                        primaryButton: {
                            /** Background color of primary button */
                            backgroundColor: '#333',
                            /** Text color of primary button */
                            color: '#fff',
                        }
                    },
                
                    /** High-level components we allow specific overrides for */
                    signingNavigationButton: {
                        finishText: 'You have finished the document! Hooray!',
                        position: 'bottom-center'
                    }
                }
            });
        
            signing.on('ready', (event) => {
                console.log('UI is rendered');
            });
        
            signing.on('sessionEnd', (event) => {
                /** The event here denotes what caused the sessionEnd to trigger, such as signing_complete, ttl_expired etc../ **/
                console.log('sessionend', event);
                window.close();
            });
        
            signing.mount('#agreement');
        })
        .catch((ex) => {
            // Any configuration or API limits will be caught here
        });
</script>

Here is what it looks like:


It could be nice to give the possibility to configure this in the admin tool

I modified the resource signing and I upload :


false
false
false
false
true
true


But I still can see the download buttons

Here is a test tool you can use to try out Focused View and the other Docusign solutions for embedded siging:
https://docusign.github.io/app-examples/embedded-signing/
By default, the Focused View signing ceremony does not include a Print button. (We plan to add it as an option in the future.)
